# None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Yoga (= 0.45.0.React)`

Tags: swift, react-native, cocoapods

I'm adding react-native to an existing swift application. For that, I'm adding following snippet to pod file.

```
 pod 'React', :path => './node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
        'Core',
        'RCTImage',
        'RCTNetwork',
        'RCTText',
        'RCTWebSocket',
    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
  ]
```

running `pod install` on this not working. Giving following error.

> None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency:
>   `Yoga (= 0.45.0.React)`.

Can someone help in resolving this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Below snippet for cocoa pods worked.

```
pod 'React', :path => './node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
        'Core',
        'RCTImage',
        'RCTNetwork',
        'RCTText',
        'RCTWebSocket',
    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
  ]

 pod 'Yoga', :path => ‘./node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec'
```